# System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type '...' from assembly '..., Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...?

Tags: c#

In the following example, I just use `parquet.net` as an example. It can be any packages in my case.

Saying I have a solution with three projects, A, X, and Y. A references X and Y. And both X and Y reference `parquet.net` but with different versions. (I cannot change the version of `parquet.net` in X and Y.

A has the following code,

```
var x = new X.Class1();
var y = new Y.Class1();

x.M();
Console.WriteLine(y.P);
```

And X project file is:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Parquet.Net" Version="1.0.114" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And X.Class1 is:

```
using Parquet.Data;

namespace X;

public class Class1
{
    public void M()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(P);
    }
}
```

Y proj file is almost the same as X except the version of `parquet.net`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Parquet.Net" Version="4.20.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And Y.Class1 is:

```
using System.Data;

namespace Y
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public DataSet? P { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It got the runtime error on the line `x.M()`? Is it a way to fix the issue without change the referenced versions of `parquet.net` in X and Y or leverage "Assembly Load Contexts"?

```
System.TypeLoadException
  HResult=0x80131522
  Message=Could not load type 'Parquet.Data.DataSet' from assembly 'Parquet, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d380b3dee6d01926'.
  Source=X
  StackTrace:
   at X.Class1.M() in C:\source\repos\ConsoleAppNet60\X\Class1.cs:line 12
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\source\repos\ConsoleAppNet60\A\Program.cs:line 7
```

Comment: Is there compatibility between versions of `parquet`? You could use a _Binding Redirect_ to have requests to one of the versions redirected to the other.